# Silverlight error 2104 - InitializeError

Tags: silverlight

I have a silver application that is giving the following error:
Error: Unhandler error in Silverlight Application
       Code: 2104
       Category: InitializeError
Code: 0
Message: 2104 An error has occurred.

I have done some research on the error and most feedback seems to be related to MIME types.

I have added the following mime types to the website in IIS: 
.xaml application/xaml+xml 
.xap application/x-silverlight-app 
.xbap application/x-ms-xbap

But I still received the same error.

Is there any other area that I should investigate or perhaps some tool that I could use to investigate what is happening.

Any assistance would be greately appreciated.

Many thanks,

Joseph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using Fiddler? This should give you some insight to the issue and/or the root cause.

Comment: thanks for the reply. No I haven't yet. I will do soon and let you know.

Comment: Fiddler definately helped. The location of the xap was being read from the web.config. and using Fiddler I noticed there was an extra space at the end of the web.config entry "htp://...xap ". Fiddler showed the browser was trying to download http://..xap%20" and made it clear where the problem was. Thanks again!!